# DotnetZip path issue

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

When using dotnetzip it does not only zip the directory like c:\users\tintin\this

but it will also zip users/tintin, which I don't want. I want it to zip the last folder so, this and all files in there.

I use the

```
AddSelectedFiles("*.*",path,true);
```

Probably really simple, but I appear to be blind for it.

Comment: I'm presuming path = c:\users\tintin\this?

Comment: Yeah just see path as any map on C or any other drive. The problem is it will add all folders before the one I want to zip aswell. So if the folder would be called "This", and I zipped it, it would go be indexed like "Users"->"TinTin"->"This"->Content. Though I just want the map "This"->Content.. I suck at explaining!

Comment: Quincy : Please provide your save method code here

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using something like:

```
AddDirectory("c:\users\tintin\this");
```

However the [documentation](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/) states:

> If you want the entries to appear in a containing directory in the zip
>   archive itself, then you should call the AddDirectory() overload that
>   allows you to explicitly specify a directory path for use in the
>   archive.

So try:

```
AddDirectory("c:\users\tintin\this", "this");
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The option to specify pathinArchive is also in the 

             AddSelectedFiles("*.*",path,dir,true);

it still Zips Users

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
zip.AddSelectedFiles(".pdf", "c:\users\tintin\this\", "");
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer. Why is this overload of `AddSelectedFiles` your recommended solution? What does it do differently to the overload that the OP has been trying? Check out [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to make better answers.